# OSX Parse - @rpath rejected by App store

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, app-store, app-store-connect, osx-yosemite

The app references frameworks which are missing. This may lead to unexpected bugs or undefined behavior.

'/Applications/CoachBase.app/Contents/MacOS/CoachBase' links against (MISSING, @relative): '@rpath/ParseOSX.framework'

I followed the guide from Parse by adding the parse framework but now it seems like it doesn't work. Any ideas?